# Rails - why can't I use activerecord exists in my scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to utilize `.exists?()` to return true or false, pretty simple. It would be nice to do the one-liner scope like so:

```
scope :any_alternates,  lambda{|apikey| Track.exists?(:track_id => apikey)}
```

Or even using this scope syntax:

```
scope :any_alternates,  ->(apikey) {Track.exists?(:track_id => apikey)}
```

But for some reason, the above scopes will return all rows in my db table when there's not a match. It works how it should when it finds a match however, but breaks if none...

I'm forced to create a method, which (to my knowledge) should be doing the same thing in the above scope:

```
def self.any_alternates(apikey)
  return Track.exists?(:track_id => apikey)
end
```

Any idea why `.exists?()` isn't working inside of my scope?

### After some testing...

If there is no match, then the scope will return all rows in the DB... (I updated above to mention that). I checked the generated query on both the scope and method to see if there's a difference, but they're the same:

```
SELECT  1 AS one FROM `tracks`  WHERE `tracks`.`track_id` = '_btbd_uUmQT8hYUK3SrJ9Q' LIMIT 1
```

### Update:

even though I'm searching on a column called `track_id`, this column is not setup as a relationship to another model. I know this is confusing, but that's how this table got setup (for good reason, beyond this issue so not worth touching on here)

Comment: Normally a scope is used to return an AREL query object and are useful for chaining. It would be odd, IMHO, to see a scope that returned a boolean. I like your class method better. You could combine both: `scope :alternatives, ->(apikey) { where(track_id: api_key) }` and `def any_alternatives?(apikey) Track.alternatives(apikey).count > 0; end`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have the right search?  A Track having a track_id implies that there is a relation between Track and another track model which would be interesting.

Also the scope syntax is off.  A scope is just a query of the table, so traditionally it is only things associated with the current model.

```
scope :any_alternates, ->(api_key) { |api_key| where(track_id: api_key }
```

Comment: Good point @Austio, but no actually. We actually do the right model, the column happens to be called `track_id` even though we're not referencing another model called Track. I'll try your syntax to see if that helps, I've never seen that syntax before... it's interesting that I need to specify the `api_key` variable twice?

Comment: If that syntax doesn't work then that means that their is something else happening.  To isolate start with going into your rails console and taking a known good api key and then doing a where.  Post the results here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing in nil?  That would cause all records to be returned.  You can drop the Track in the scope, like this:

```
scope :any_alternates,  lambda{|apikey| exists?(:track_id => apikey)}
```

Here is what happens when you pass in nil:

```
> Track.any_alternates(nil).count
Track Exists (1.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "track" WHERE "tracks"."track_id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

instead of passing in a value:

```
> Track.any_alternates('X4DBA36gbtqgWl4F1')
Track Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "tracks" WHERE "tracks"."track_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["track_id", "X4DBA36gbtqgWl4F1"]]
```

Comment: I'm passing in an actual value so I know it's not a nil issue... though I'm interested to compare the generated statement using the scope versus defined method... I'll double check that to see if it's somehow interpreting as nil.